# How to extract text between a string and a character right before it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have this piece of text:

`GINC/weary/crazy/RMSD=2316`

I was hoping there was a way to extract what lies between the 2nd forward slash `/` and `/RMSD=2316`. In other words, I want to look for the string `/RMSD=2316` and extract whatever lies between it and the forward slash that precedes it.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed, without any positional assumptions:

```
echo 'GINC/weary/crazy/RMSD=2316' | \
      sed -n 's!.*/\([^/]*\)/RMSD=2316.*!\1!p'
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F/ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="RMSD=2316") print $(i-1)}' t
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
cut -d/ -f3
```

`-d/` is the slash delimiter

`-f3` means third column

Answer (score 1):

Since you have marked this `bash`

```
var='GINC/weary/crazy/RMSD=2316'
var1=${var%/RMSD=2316}
echo $var1
echo ${var1##*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*\/\([^\/]\+\)\/RMSD=2316/\1/'
```

This matches all text leading up to a forward-slash, captures all non-forward-slash characters leading up to `/RMSD=2316`, and replaces the entire match with the captured characters.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
str=GINC/weary/crazy/RMSD=2316
echo "$str" | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m|.*?/.*?/(.*)/RMSD=2316|'
```